# MvvmCross and Google Analytics with MvxAnalytics - How to use?

Tags: android, google-analytics, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using the Google analytics plugin for MvvmCross with the following namespace:-

OCS.MvvmCross.Plugins.MvxAnalytics

https://www.nuget.org/packages/OCS.MvvmCross.Plugins.MvxAnalytics

There isn't any documentation on how to use/implement it, from my discovery, the AnalyticsConfiguration needs to be defined, then added to the DroidAnalyticsService.Configuration.

Inside the AnalyticsConfiguration, there is TrackingId, which I understand, log levels and whether to report UncaughtExceptions (set to true)

The PluginBootstrap file is included which is great, but joining the last dots are a bit of a headscratch.

Any ideas how to get this working?  I've messaged the creators so if they email me back, I'll post the details here.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set it up and it seems that it's working properly.
You have to setup all properties inside Configuration object and then it works.

```
var analyticsService = new DroidAnalyticsService();
analyticsService.Configuration.AppName = "Your app name";
analyticsService.Configuration.AnonymizeIp = true;
analyticsService.Configuration.AppVersion = "App version fro xml";
analyticsService.Configuration.TrackingId = "Tracking id from google";
analyticsService.Configuration.DispatchPeriod = 30;
analyticsService.Configuration.ReportUncaughtExceptions = true;
```